# How to judge whether accept read Contacts permission or not for android?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, read-write

I have a problem!
in developing.I have declared permission in Manifest file .

There is a requirement:if I refused the read Contacts permission in system security software(like MIUI/EmotionUI/Flyme etc.),when I open this Activity next time,there should show a dialog to tell me "you have refused current software to read contacts,please go to setting and accept this permission".

But now ,I don't know how to check whether I accept this permission or not,I need help.

Help me ,thanks!

Comment: Should Google stuff before posting on here. Just checkout the Android docs about permissions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check)

Answer (score 0):

use these two methods for checking the permission and request for permission if its not available

```
    private boolean checkPermission(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)){
            Toast.makeText(context,"read contact permission.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this way,but it didn't work,then I scan the ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale comment ,it is effected in SDK 23,ActivityCompat.requestPermissions seems called fail,I override the onRequestPermissionsResult but it doesn't work.  how to solve in pre-23?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

Comment: is it inside application tag ?

Comment: not inside application tag, it's the same level with application tag